# CSV file getting downloaded but not saved to computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I'm working on a Django project where I create a csv file using some data that I have and then I want the user to be able to download it. The file is being created in views.py, which looks like this:

```
def generate_csv_response(modelset, field_names, filename='export.csv'):
    """ Generate a CSV for all field_names in a DB model

        :param field_names is a dictionary which contains the model field name
            as a key and the CSV header display name as it's value
    """
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{filename}"'

    # create the CSV writer and write a header row to the file
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow([v for _, v in field_names.items()]) # display names are the values

    # write a row of all specified fields for each model in the modelset
    for m in modelset:
        row = [getattr(m, field) for field in field_names]
        writer.writerow(row)

    # return the generated HTTP response
    return response

class ConfigRuleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = ConfigRule.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ConfigRuleSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser | ReadOnlyUser]
    config_rule_connector = AWSConfigRuleConnector()

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'], permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny])
    def refresh(self, request):
        account_id = json.loads(request.body)['account_id']
        if not account_id:
            logger.warn('Got blank account_id from ajax request: %s', account_id)

        if self.config_rule_connector.update(account_id):
            return Response(data={'updated': True, 'count': ConfigRule.objects.count()})
        return Response(data={'updated': False, 'error': 'Config Rule could not be updated', 'count': 0}, status=500)

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post', 'get'], permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny])
    def csv(self, request):
        """ Get the ConfigRule information as a CSV """
        return generate_csv_response(
            ConfigRule.objects.all(),
            field_names={
                'name': 'Name',
                'aws_account_id': 'AWS Account ID',
                'arn': 'ARN',
                'owner': 'Owner',
                'description': 'Description',
                'state': 'State',
            },
            filename='config_rule_report.csv',
        )
```

and this is what I'm doing to download it using ajax:

```
{% block csv-button %}
    <button id="csv-btn" class="button is-link">CSV</button>
{% endblock %}
```

```
        var csvBtn = $("#csv-btn");

        // allow the table to be resync'd at any time by clicking the button
        csvBtn.click(function() {
            csvBtn.addClass("is-loading");
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ api_csv_url }}",
                method: "GET",
                contentType: "text/csv",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("File has been successfully downloaded.");
                },
                complete: function() {
                    // complete runs on failure or success, so the button
                    // will always be re-enabled if a failure occurs
                    csvBtn.removeClass("is-loading");
                }
            });
        });
```

[image]

The file does get downloaded since I can go into dev tools and then network and I see it there. csv/ is the file being downloaded and I'm having difficulties getting it to download into the user's computer. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can’t be done by Ajax, as JS wont write to disk, so you have 2 solutions

1. Use [FileSystem API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/) which is very new and not supported by all browswers.
2. Use a classic anchor tag to download the file, as you return the response, the browser will intercept and handle the download.